# Is it possible to mix Eclipse project types?

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse

Is it possible to mix Eclipse project types?

If it is, what is the preferred method of doing this?

I am writing a RESTlet application that uses Java and InfiniteGraph in the back-end/middle-end and for this I need Java. I am also writing the front-end and this relies on CSS, HTML and Javascript. All the files are in one respiratory and I usually check it out as a Java project. When I switch to Eclipse's Javascript perspective, I am not able to use a lot of the features because "The resource is not on the build path of JavaScript project."

Thanks in advance,

Arturo Aparicio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can, no need to switch perspective as it still a java project, just update `project facets`